# How can I find the function of a python module?

Tags: python, function, opencv, module

I am using OpenCV, and I want to see what the "rectangle" function is. 
I can use the dir(module) function, to get at the function definition, and name, but I don't know how to view the actual function. I am Using Linux (Ubuntu 16.04), and I'm wondering if the libraries are in "/usr/local/" or some other place. The OpenCV cv2 python library is just an example, I want to know how to view any function of a library, imported into python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways :

- If you want to get the source code on runtime you can use `inspect.getsourcelines(object)` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines)
- If you want to find where the module is you can simply `print(module.__file__)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the wonderful [IPython](https://ipython.org/) interactive shell.

You can see the definition of any function (or in general of any object whose source code is available) by appending two question marks `??` to its name. Below is a short example run on my terminal:

```
$ ipython
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jan 27 2016, 11:42:08) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.3.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import urllib

In [2]: urllib.urlopen??
Type:        function
String form: <function urlopen at 0x2b56465ac578>
File:        /sw/python/2.7.9/Linux.x86_64/lib/python2.7/urllib.py
Definition:  urllib.urlopen(url, data=None, proxies=None)
Source:
def urlopen(url, data=None, proxies=None):
    """Create a file-like object for the specified URL to read from."""
    from warnings import warnpy3k
    warnpy3k("urllib.urlopen() has been removed in Python 3.0 in "
             "favor of urllib2.urlopen()", stacklevel=2)

    global _urlopener
    if proxies is not None:
        opener = FancyURLopener(proxies=proxies)
    elif not _urlopener:
        opener = FancyURLopener()
        _urlopener = opener
    else:
        opener = _urlopener
    if data is None:
        return opener.open(url)
    else:
        return opener.open(url, data)
```